# Reduce amount of queries for generic foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have these models:

```
class RegionPage(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class SomePage(models.Model):
    someotherfield = models.ForeignKey('SomeClass')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Link(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntergerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Obviously, I can use neither `select_related` nor `prefetch_related` to get access to someotherfield and area fields. But is there any way to reduce amount of queries when you work with generic foreign keys?